# Bing maps Silverlight Zoom slider

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

Is there a way to change the style or position of the bing maps silverlight defualt zoom silder?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can hide the default slider and create your own attaching to the map events to get zoom / pan etc working with your control

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this with XAML resembling:

```
<Grid>
  <!-- MAP -->
  <MapControl:Map x:Name="_map" />
  <!-- ZOOM SLIDER -->
  <Slider Style="{StaticResource MapZoomSliderStyle}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Margin="40" Width="18" Height="300"
          Value="{Binding ElementName=_map, Path=ZoomLevel}"
          Minimum="1" Maximum="20"/>
</Grid>
```

Binding the max/min values is a bit tricky, as they change depending upon where on the map you're viewing, and the map mode (road/aerial).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788119/how-to-bind-maximum-and-minimum-zoom-levels-in-bing-maps-silverlight) for further discussion.